# Is it possibile to connect two iphones via wifi without a LAN?

Tags: iphone, wifi, adhoc

I need two iphones to communicate (send and receive messages) without being inside a LAN.
I read that Game Kit Framework makes this possibile but only via bluetooth (is that right?). The application that I have to create need a larger radius than bluetooth so I need wifi but I can't have a Laptop that create the network 'cause this application will run on the outside just between iphone (without internet connection).

Is that possibile?
In that case, where do I have to take a look? (Bonjour, Game Kit Framework..)

Thank you

Comment: There are 3rd party applications I can download for my nokia e90 that let me host a wireless network. This means it's definitly possible with WiFi, or you could actually use an external application so that you can connect the two phones by LAN first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Here's the deal ...***

1. GameKit works with ***EITHER*** bluetooth or wifi. It's completely automatic.  Annoyingly you CAN NOT choose between the paradigm.
2. From 2016, almost all iPhones / iPads can create a "hotspot" WiFi network, yes.

Comment: Gamekit works well, but under some circumstances it can take a while to establish a connection.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes that QA is incredibly out of date.  SO don't like people editing answers, but I did so anyway.